# Convert the collection object to string or array in php

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to get the count of each variable in an array.
Am getting the object like [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,4,6]

```
$array = array(12,43,66,21,56,43,43,78,78,100,43,43,43,21);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
```

This function is the solution. But I can't make the collection object to string or array.

Comment: I don't think that your question makes sense. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve, by explaining the problem, providing details as to how you get from the input to the desired output, and post the code you have written thus far.

Comment: What do you mean? [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) returns an array.

Comment: Am getting the object as [1,1,1,1,2,2,3]. But I want it as 1,1,1,1,2,2,3, How do I get this? If I get like this only, I can apply array_count_values and get the duplicate results

Comment: Am getting the collection of id's with the following command line: $id = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->pluck('id'); I want to make it as string.

Comment: @Kayal You get `Array
(
    [12] => 1
    [43] => 6
    [66] => 1
    [21] => 2
    [56] => 1
    [78] => 2
    [100] => 1
)`. Which is an associative array.

Comment: @Pautomagi , Answer is what I expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this is tagged with laravel, in that case you could do collect($vals)->toArray(). If I remember correctly.

edit: you are looking for the php function implode.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

`string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )`

Comment: yaa.. I got the answer. Thank you so much